# Invalid unicode pair detected during code set conversion in restful webservice

Tags: java, web-services, rest, character-encoding

I am trying to retrieve a blob object from oracle db. The blob object represents a word document stored in oracle db.

I retrieve the blob and convert into java bytes with utf8 encoding and pass on to a restful webservice. Restful webservice receives the blob object and passes on to another client as json. At this point in time I get the following exception. Can anyone please help in fixing this ?

```
org.omg.CORBA.DATA_CONVERSION: WARNING: IOP02410006: Invalid unicode pair detected during code set conversion  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 6  completed: No
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:248)  at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:95)    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.handleFullLogging(WrapperGenerator.java:387) at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.access$400(WrapperGenerator.java:107)at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator$2.invoke(WrapperGenerator.java:511)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.proxy.CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.java:99) at $Proxy200.badUnicodePair(Unknown Source) at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CodeSetConversion$JavaCTBConverter.convertCharArray(CodeSetConversion.java:335)   at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CodeSetConversion$JavaCTBConverter.convert(CodeSetConversion.java:250)    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_2.write_wstring(CDROutputStream_1_2.java:470)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.writeWStringValue(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:737)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:956)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:976)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:706)
    at tputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:962)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:976)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.simpleWriteObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:196)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl$14.write(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:394)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:200)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:152)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.codegen.CodegenStubBase.invoke(CodegenStubBase.java:227)
    at gov.ca.lc.refdata.__VotesRefDataBeanRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.getBillAnalysis(gov/ca/lc/refdata/__VotesRefDataBeanRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.java)
    at gov.ca.lc.refdata._VotesRefDataBeanRemote_Wrapper.getBillAnalysis(gov/ca/lc/refdata/_VotesRefDataBeanRemote_Wrapper.java)
    at gov.ca.lc.refdata.VotesWS.getBillAnalysis(VotesWS.java:102)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:260)
    at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode(CharsetEncoder.java:781)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CodeSetConversion$JavaCTBConverter.convertCharArray(CodeSetConversion.java:324)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_2.write_wstring(CDROutputStream_1_2.java:470)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.writeWStringValue(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:738)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:956)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:977)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:706)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.write_value(CDROutputObject.java:528)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.writeObjectField(IIOPOutputStream.java:775)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.outputClassFields(IIOPOutputStream.java:846)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.defaultWriteObjectDelegate(IIOPOutputStream.java:245)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.outputObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:614)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.simpleWriteObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:196)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:235)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueWithVersion(ValueHandlerImpl.java:216)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:180)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.callWriteValue(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:852)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.writeRMIIIOPValueType(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:837)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:962)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:977)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_abstract_interface(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:692)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.write_abstract_interface(CDROutputObject.java:546)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.writeAbstractObject(Util.java:494)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(IIOPOutputStream.java:176)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:327)
    at java.util.LinkedList.writeObject(LinkedList.java:942)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.invokeObjectWriter(IIOPOutputStream.java:646)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.outputObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:612)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.simpleWriteObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:196)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:235)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueWithVersion(ValueHandlerImpl.java:216)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:180)
    at
```

Comment: For your information I already tried doing  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON+ ";charset=utf-8")

Comment: Word document is a binary file, it makes no sense to convert it to UTF-8

Comment: Hi Esailija, so is there any way to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The code is throwing an exception because it is validating that some character data is valid. Not all code unit sequences form valid code points in Unicode encodings.

Strings are not binary-safe as turning `byte` data into `char` data involves a transcoding operation. The input `byte` data must conform to the encoding expected by the transcoder or data loss results.

> The blob object represents a word document stored in oracle db.
>
> I retrieve the blob and convert into java bytes with utf8 encoding and pass on to a restful webservice.
>
> Restful webservice receives the blob object and passes on to another client as json.

The binary Word document cannot be translated into character data without data loss, at least not without encoding it in a form like [Base64](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64&ei=_vHSULHjF-iY1AWJyYGACg&usg=AFQjCNFxJAMXAr4Jc-0wQvhcp_q4nZlf5w&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.d2k). If you encode the file as Base64 then the receiver will need to know how to decode it.

My understanding of the transformations involved:

```
BLOB (bytes)
   > String (data is already corrupt here)
          > UTF-8 bytes 
                      > String
                             > JSON
                                  > junk
```

This design is flawed.

This would be better:

```
BLOB (bytes)
   > Base64 String
                 > UTF-8 bytes
                             > Base64 String
                                           > JSON
                                                > Base64 String
                                                              > BLOB
```

This might not be exactly what you need, but the point is that all transformations must be reciprocal and lossless.

*Note that JSON is always encoded in a Unicode transformation format or it is by definition not JSON. The default is UTF-8 as defined by the specification.*